# How to load classpath resources in java while skipping content from local maven repo

Tags: java, spring, maven

I'm getting resources from the classpath as following.

```
Resource[] compiledResources = loader.getResources("classpath:jasper/compiled/*.*");
```

However when I load resources like this I'm getting content form the same jar which is already in the local maven M2 repository; since it's already in the classpath.

Is there a way to avoid this ?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you need to include a custom jar in classpath rather than utilizing the m2 repo based jar. you can add the dependency with scope "provided" and add localPath option with appropriate location of jar for the same.

Comment: Jar file is already bundled in the war file. But at the execution of the web-app it find both resources; one already bundled and other one in the M2 repo(which is not expected).

Comment: explicitly mark it excluded in the pom to ignore it.